# What is the formula to calculate the velocity of an airstream based on pressure differential?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I have an air tank at 100 psi above ambient pressure (roughly 14 psi). If a small spigot is opened, what will the velocity of the core of the air stream be?

I realize friction will slow the outside of the stream, but was curious, as large storms such as hurricanes do a lot with a pressure differential of around 3 psi.

What mathematical formula would describe the velocity of the stream.  Under what conditions?

Comment: Google ‘choked flow’ as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow depends on the **ratio of static pressure** and the **nozzle design**. In your case without a properly designed nozzle the flow will be **choked** and reach the **speed of sound** $c_s^{(air)} \approx 340 \frac{m}{s}$. The [following formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressible_flow#Isentropic_flow_Mach_number_relationships) can be derived assuming [one-dimensional isentropic flow of an ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressible_flow#One-dimensional_flow).

---

The main criterion for the flow velocity (generally given by the [Mach number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number) $Ma := \frac{U}{c_s}$) is the ratio of ambient pressure $p_{ambient}$ to static pressure inside the container $p_0$ as you can see in [this graph](https://neutrium.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Choked-Flow1.png). As a reference pressure ratio we take the ratio of critical pressure $p_{crit}$ (which corresponds to the static pressure in the sonic case for $Ma = 1$) to $p_0$ as the Mach number characterises the communication up- and downstream.*

$$\frac{p_{crit}}{p_0} = \left( \frac{2}{\gamma + 1}\right)^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1} \approx 0.528$$

- For a pressure ratio of ambient pressure to static pressure inside the container $\frac{p_{ambient}}{p_0}$ lower than the ratio of critical to static pressure the flow will accelerate towards the smallest cross-section of the nozzle and then decelerate (top line in the aforementioned graph).
- If the ambient pressure is lower than the critical pressure but the nozzles is not designed accordingly, the flow will accelerate towards the smallest cross-section, reach the speed of sound $c_s$ but not be able to accelerate any further even though the pressure ratio would be large enough. This type of flow is said to be [choked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow) (second line from top in the graph). The reason for this is the [lack of downstream communication for sonic and supersonic flows](https://neutrium.net/fluid_flow/choked-flow/).
- If the ambient pressure is lower than the critical pressure and the nozzle a properly designed [convergent-divergent nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle) the flow can accelerate further and reach supersonic velocities. For more information [see](http://www.engapplets.vt.edu/fluids/CDnozzle/cdinfo.html).

---

*) For the limiting case of $Ma=0$, which corresponds to an incompressible fluid, any information travels up- and downstream equally fast. With increasing Mach number the information travels up- and downstream increasingly non-uniform and for sonic $Ma = 1$ and supersonic flows $Ma > 1$ there will be no communication downstream anymore. This is also the reason for the difference in sub- and supersonic jet design: A subsonic airliner will be streamlined as the incoming fluid senses the geometry of the airplane in advance while for a supersonic jet traveling at supersonic speeds this is not the case and it will have to "slice" the fluid.

Comment: My application is a blown out window of a Concorde at 60,000 feet.  Window area: $0.25 feet^2$. Fuselage volume $pi×5^2×150feet^2$. Exhaust plume velocity 360 mph (rough guess based on tornado pressure differential), averaged as flow would slow as Pinternal/Pexternal approached 1.  Initial internal pressure 14 psi, external pressure 1 psi.  100 seconds was my initial "ball park" estimate.  I wish to improve it, or at least validate it as reasonably close.  Please show a sample calculation for this application.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni You can make a simplified calculation assuming the ideal gas law, the first law of thermodynamics for an open system and the correlations for the critical flow. It is a standard textbook example. I will try to link you to a complete calculation from an English textbook later. So far I only have scans of my handwritten notes of my German-language higher thermodynamics class. But in the end that is just a crude approximation...

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I could not find an English textbook with a similar problem but I can send you a pdf-document from my university in German that contains several examples regarding this topic. One in particular is very similar to what you want to do: There is a mass flow out of a pressurised container but the temperature inside the container is held constant throughout the process (it is heated). You would have to change the constant temperature to adiabatic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Ideal_gas_(reversible_process) and of course the magnitude of the different parameters.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I could not find your Stackexchange chat profile. Just send me an invitation to a chat room when you have time. I'll give you the file and translate the task, so you can give it a shot and modify it.

Comment: thanks so much.  I am realizing orifice size can be important as pressure gradient lessens and friction slows plume, which is why a hurricane can reach such speeds at 3 psi while an aerosol can plume may not.  Inertia has to be overcome to accelerate the fluid (air), but with a small orifice the distance of acceleration is much less. Mass flow from a pressurized container seems to be the model.  With the Concorde, plume will cool from decompression, but may still be warmer than ambient air at 60,000 feet.  (Metric calculations definitely OK, too)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102857/discussion-between-2b-t-and-robert-digiovanni).